# Multitenancy with spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there any way to make spring-data-elasticsearch to work for multitenant application?

I've made it to work without multitenancy, but I don't know how can I have multiple indices or multiple nodes for each tenant? I want to know if there is any way to define different index name for each tenant or to add transient property in my entity class which is annotated properly with `@Document(...)`. When I tried to do that problem was that `@Transient` is also marked in `ElasticSearchRepository`.
Any idea?

Comment: can you please elaborate more ? when you say multi tanant, is it for searching on multiple indices ?

Comment: Yes I would like to have multiple indices for each tenant. With spring-data-elasticsearch I haven't found any solution like that. So any other solution like multiple nodes or whatever would be appropriate for me

Comment: you wanna configure elasticsearch in single node arch where  more than one user @ a time [or] multi node arch??

Comment: single node arch with more than one tenants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you've got to understand how Elasticsearch (and especially Lucene) store your data.

Elasticsearch's naming convention "index" and "type" is a bit misleading and most likely **not** what you first thought!

---

If you create a type (`id, field1, field2`) within an index in Elasticsearch, it will create something similar to a SQL Table:

```
id     | field1 | field2
-------------------------
string | int    | boolean
```

What you might **not** expect is, what happens when you add a second type (`id, type2field`) to that index. The index mapping will become:

```
id     | field1 | field2  | type2field
--------------------------------------
string | int    | boolean | string
```

This happens, because there's **no** type mapping - even if Elasticsearch will make it look like that. **There's only a mapping at index level!** This way, you will most likely end up having a lot of empty fields.

---

Though in general and especially for a multi tenency setup, you should create an **index** per class - **not** type! You should use the type for separating similar shaped data, i.e. use types for your tenants. Or add an additional field to your mapping for identifying the tenant.

---

Read more about it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html#_type_takeaways

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution I made to this problem. By default, We would add an index with our POJO annotation of `@Document` which is okay.However there are cases where we would want to have differen indexes per client so I decided to create them myself. I've used the ElasticSearch Template to create indexes for different tenants rather than relying on Spring Data ElasticSearch repo for saving. Here's what  I did

```
    IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder()
                        .withId("ID")
                        .withIndexName("yourtenant")
                        .withType("yourtype")
                        .withObject(obj)
                        .build();

    es.index(indexQuery)
```

Comment: Elasticsearch's First Commandment: "Thou shalt not use 'type' for your class mappings (in 95% of the cases - there are exceptions like inheritance and time series data, etc.)". See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I've made solution to this problem. It might not be the best solution but I didn't found anything else.
I've added field `tenantName` to my indexed classes and marked it with annotation `@javax.persistence.Transient` instead of `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`. And after that I am making my search queries with condition that tenant must be tenant to which current user belongs.

Answer (score 1):

I found quite an easy solution with SpEL for prefixing indexes like

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@prefixProvider.getPrefix()}_foo", type="bar")
```

`prefixProvider` being just a regular spring bean.